# Make Polyline Longer at runtime

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a **google map** application where i am moving markers on a **polyline**. I am generating a new destination point(*latlng coordinates*). I would like to extend the **polyline** to this new destination point.

Can some one tell me how i can move the end point of a **polyline** to another point on the map.

I have used `polyline[index].getPath()` in here i can see all the latlng coordinate pairs that make up the route. How to add to this route to make it longer or shorter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple.  If you merely wanted to add an additional point to the existing array of points, this works:

```
var currentPath = polyline[index].getPath();
var newPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(40.781321,-73.965855);
currentPath.push(newPoint);
polyline[index].setPath(currentPath);
```

If you wanted however to change where the current last point is at, try this instead:

```
var currentPath = polyline[index].getPath();
var newPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(40.781321,-73.965855);
currentPath.setAt(currentPath.getLength()-1, newPoint);
polyline[index].setPath(currentPath);
```

Comment: This should update the end point only? Just confirming. Thanks a lot let you know how this goes.

Comment: ah, actually that will only add an additional point to be the end one.  If you only want to change the LAST endpoint to be somewhere else, the code will be slightly different.  Will update my answer here with that too.

Comment: Yes, please see my updated answer, the second version simply changes where the last point in the array is

Comment: just one more question is it possible to snap the extension of the polyline to road?

Comment: also would i have to use  directionsService to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd be able to do that, that's probably worth a new question